# Error al cargar app en emulador Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Hola soy iniciado en Android Studio y estoy desarrollando una app que al  hacer click en un botón te lleve a una pagina web. El problema es que no me carga la app en el emulador me salta un mensaje "Unfortunately , nuev_app has stopped".
Como anotació contar, que la app me funcionaba perfectamente en otro proyecto que y he copiado y pegado cada parte de codigo de uno a otro proyecto y en este segundo no me funciona, la guarde en una memoria usb y al abrirlo en el pc me da errores por todos lados

Gracias de antemano por vuestras respuestas.

```
----------Este es error que aparece en Logcat


04-24 10:15:50.983 13503-13503/com.example.nuev_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nuev_app, PID: 13503
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nuev_app/com.example.nuev_app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.nuev_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.nuev_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.nuev_app:drawable/bkg_app_tiempo2" (7f060056)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060056 a=-1 r=0x7f060056}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:493)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:489)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:575)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.nuev_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 




---------Esto es lo que tengo puesto en MainActivity.java

package com.example.nuev_app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    String url ="https://www.eltiempo.es/";
    public void click(View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"has pulsado el boton",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this,browser.class);
        String valor="madrid";
        String resultado= url+valor;
        intent.putExtra("resultado",resultado);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}


---------Esto es lo que tengo en el Activity_main.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg_app_tiempo2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="268dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.218"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_app_tiempo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_micro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:onClick="click"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_micro" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



---------Esto tengo en el build.gradle



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nuev_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: ¿En que sistema operativo ocurrió este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo parece ser que hay archivos a los que está intentando acceder (iconos, imágenes, etc) que no están disponibles por alguna razón. Es posible que al copiar el proyecto no copiases estas imágenes e iconos?

Fíjate que todos los elementos a los que se hace referencia de la carpeta drawable estén contenidos en dicha carpeta.

Parece ser que por ejemplo en la línea `android:background="@drawable/bkg_app_tiempo2"`, la imagen `bkg_app_tiempo2` falta.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Pablo lo primero gracias por contestas. Lo he mirado pero todos los recursos de imágenes los tengo en la carpeta drawable. Tengo la duda de que al lado del nombre de los recursos sale un (v24) ejemplo: bkg_app_tiempo2.png(v24)

Comment: En principio eso no debería ser un problema. Voy a echarle otro ojo a ver

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo indicado en el LogCat:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   "com.example.nuev_app:drawable/bkg_app_tiempo2" (7f060056)  is not a
>   Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060056 a=-1
>   r=0x7f060056}

No se puede inflar el layout puesto que el recurso llamado `bkg_app_tiempo2` no es en realidad un `Drawable` soportado por tu sistema operativo, posiblemente es un [Vector Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources).

Para este caso agrega tu imagen dentro de `/drawable` y tu [Vector Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources) dentro de `/drawable-v21`, ejemplo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]